# Вопрос насчет обработчика php

Tags: php, mysql

Созрел такой вопрос:
Есть форма, пользователь вводит данные, форма передаёт на обработчик, например send.php, тот в свою очередь соединяется с mySql и вносит данные в БД. Что будет, если одновременно обратятся к обработчику допустим 5 пользователей? А если 50 или 500? Что произойдет и как избежать ошибок?

Comment: Все зависит от настроек и мощности вашего сервера. В принципе ничего не произойдет, в mysql создается по умолчанию очередь запросов и если в вашем файле запросы "быстрые" к БД, то пользователи просто почувствуют небольшую задержку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых никто не соединяется к файлу напрямую, а соединяются к PHP-FPM или Apache MOD PHP, которые обрабатывают эти файлы в соответствии с заданными параметрами и конфигурацией.

### Веб-сервер

Далее, сначала вы должны понять что такое CGI, запрос сначала уходит на веб-сервер, потом по этому стандарту уходит на модуль обработки (php).

[image: Как работает обработка запроса]

**Common Gateway Interface**, "общий интерфейс шлюза" — это стандарт, который описывает, как веб-сервер должен запускать прикладные программы (скрипты), как должен передавать им параметры HTTP-запроса, как скрипты должны передавать результаты своей работы веб-серверу. Прикладную программу взаимодействующую с веб-сервером по протоколу CGI принято называть шлюзом, хотя более распространено название **CGI-скрипт или CGI-программа**.

Дальнейшее развитие технологии CGI, является более производительным и безопасным, снимает множество ограничений CGI-программ.

**FastCGI** программа работает следующим образом: скрипт единожды загружается в память в качестве демона (независимо от HTTP-сервера), а затем входит в цикл обработки запросов от HTTP-сервера. Один и тот же процесс-скрипт обрабатывает несколько различных запросов один за другим, что отличается от работы в CGI-режиме, когда на каждый запрос создается отдельный процесс, "умирающий" после окончания обработки.

По сути, все просто, веб-сервер на основе модуля создает дополнительные процессы для обработки (workerы) или подключается к какому-то демону передавая ему запросы, а тот самостоятельно выбирает количество процессов для обработки. Естественно, один процесс может обрабатывать больше одного запроса.

**Для улучшения производительности**, вам нужно увеличить количество одновременных процессов, количество коннектов, смотрите инструкции по настройке конфигурации вашей связки веб-сервера и модуля обработки PHP.

### База данных

При соединении с базой данных, PHP создает соединение с ней и выполняет подключение, поэтому база данных тоже должна быть корректно настроена, но в целом менеджер процессов имеет такое понятие как connection polling, который содержат в себе все соединения с базой и позволяют эффективно их использовать. Хотя я думаю в вашем случае это не будет проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Я подозреваю, что Вы опасаетесь некорректной вставки данных. Сразу на ум приходят два сценария: падение сервера или наличие запросов, в которых сразу же используются результаты предыдущих запросов. Для обоих случаев ответ один: если у Вас в обработчике выполняется всего 1 запрос, то Вам не о чем беспокоиться - даже если произойдет падение сервера, MySQL позаботится о том, чтобы запрос либо полностью выполнился либо полностью не выполнился, если же у Вас в обработчике выполняется блок запросов, то можно воспользоваться **транзакциями**.